# Set content width of Webview with remote url in Appcelerator

Tags: webview, appcelerator

I have a webview with content loaded in from a remote url. Now this content is to wide for the screen of my device. I want to adjust the content width NOT the webview width. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to inject new CSS properties when the webView has loaded. See this gist example:

https://gist.github.com/dawsontoth/811993